# Ansible API Call vRealize Automation 7 catalog Item error when sending POST request

Tags: json, dictionary, post, ansible, ansible-tower

I am trying to make an API call to execute a Catalog Item in VRA 7. I am sending a JSON in the POST body request. This it the JSON

What does that mean please? I am still new with learning Ansible and all the Map/Dictionnary/Array objects so I am not sure how to resolve this. What would be the correct way to set the content of serverArray?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As I see you're trying to pass a wrong variable type in **serverArray**: `"{{serverArray}}"` which is just a string, but your facts contains a list inside of dict:

```
serverArray: {[abcddne706]}
```

You can test running the next ansible tasks for better understanding:

```
    - name: "set variable"
      set_fact:
        foo: "abcddne706"

    - name: "set wrappers for foo"
      set_fact:
        bar: "{[ {{ foo }} ]}"
        baz:
          - "{[ {{ foo }} ]}"

    - name: "Show foo variable as as string"
      debug:
        var: foo

    - name: "Show the results of foo put inside of list and wrapped by dict"
      debug:
        var: bar

    - name: "Show the results as foo put inside of list and wrapped by dict then set as list item"
      debug:
        var: baz
```

with the next output:

```
TASK [Show foo variable as as string] *********************************************************************
ok: [10.1.1.1] => {                                                 
    "foo": "abcddne706"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
}

TASK [Show the results of foo put inside of list and wrapped by dict] *********************************************************************
ok: [10.1.1.1] => {                                                 
    "bar": "{[ abcddne706 ]}"                                          
}

TASK [Show the results as foo put inside of list and wrapped by dict then set as list item] *********************************************************************
ok: [10.10.1.1] => {                                                 
    "baz": [                                                           
        "{[ abcddne706 ]}"                                             
    ]                                                                  
}
```

So number two looks like your serverArray ansible fact.

You can also iterate over list items with different keys and values in ansible. Every list item is a dict with two keys and values pair:

```yaml
- name: "Show some keys and values"
  debug:
    msg: >
      Here is a dict item: {{ item }}
      which consists of: item.key1 = {{ item.key1 }}; item.key2 = {{ item.key2 }}
  with_items:
    - { key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2' }
    - { key1: 'value3', key2: 'value4' }
```

Output:

```
TASK [Show some keys and values] *********************************************************************
ok: [10.1.1.1] => (item={'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}) => {
    "msg": "Here is a dict item: {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'} which consists of: item.key1 = value1; item.key2 = value2\n"
}
ok: [10.1.1.1] => (item={'key1': 'value3', 'key2': 'value4'}) => {
    "msg": "Here is a dict item: {'key1': 'value3', 'key2': 'value4'} which consists of: item.key1 = value3; item.key2 = value4\n"
}
```

Maybe it might brings some difference explanation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Appreciate it. I tried your different methods however I still have the same error.  

I am not sure if I need to send a list or just a string. Basically, i need to send one or many hostname (so a list, I believe). But I’m not sure what a MultipleLiteral or what MultipleValued type means?

"message": "The value for the field "serverArray" is not a ,MultipleLiteral but the field is  defined as Multivalued,
"code": 11011

Comment: No prob, 'MultipleValued' sounds about dicts. So I have updated my answer about dicts, keys and values. Could you please share what your have typed in your json and ansible step for several hosts?

Comment: I managed to find the solution. Thank you for you help!! I had to delete some information